# django can we prefetch related field on a select related model?

Tags: django, django-orm

I need to get the latest image of the creator for each event.

For example I have 3 models:

```
class Event(..):
   create_by = ForeignKey(User, related_name='events_set')

class User(..):
...

class ProfileImage(..):
   user = ForeignKey(User, related_name='profile_images_set')
   image = ImageField(..)
```

So i need to get detail info about Event, I have got a guery like this:

```
Event.objects.all().prefetch_related('..').select_related('created_by')
```

The problem is that I also need to get the last image of event creator. 
I tried `Prefetch` but it only works to control `prefetch_related`.
Something like this:

```
Event.objects.all().prefetch_related('..').select_related(Prefetch('created_by', queryset=User.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('profile_images_set', queryset=ProfileImages.objects.filter(id=OuterRef('pk').latest('pk'))))
```

**UPDATE**
Current working queryset:

```
Event.objects.all().prefetch_related(.., 'created_by__profile_images_set')
```

But it fetches all images of creator.
ALso I tried:

```
Event.objects.all().prefetch_related(..,Prefetch('created_by__profile_images_set',queryset=ProfileImage.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('pk')).latest('pk')))
```

But I got an error:
`ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.`

Comment: Can you try `Event.objects.all().prefetch_related('created_by__image')` ? I don't understand why you need to get the latest user

Comment: @Benbb96 oops there is an error I need to get the latest image of creator
I changed my queryset